# If x = 2 and y = 5, then the set S = {k ∈ Z | 2k ≤ 5} is bounded above by y/x = 5/2 & thus has a least upper bound α in the real numbers.

Tags: real-analysis

If x = 2 and y = 5, then the set S = {k ∈ Z | 2k ≤ 5} is bounded above by y/x = 5/2 & thus has a least upper bound α in the real numbers.
i think  this is correct statement